# Videos not clear while playing with video view in android

Tags: android, android-widget

Guys 
I am new to android and want to write a simple application that plays a video in android using video view. I have written the code it is working but the view is not clear. It is blurred. What should I do?? Please Help.

Is there any alternative to video view to achieve that...?? I want to play the recorded video from android phones

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. Either the quality of the video might be low or you would have tried it in a emulator. Sometimes it is possible for emulator to have some problems with playing video which I have personally faced. So you have to try it in a real device.

And regarding alternative for videoview, there is no such alternatives available I believe. But still videoview should be simple to play a video.